# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action not duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i know this error AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action occur when render multi time

but already use solution `and return`

```
class FrequentMethodController < ApplicationController
  def post_exist?(post_id)
    post = Post.find_by_id(post_id)
    render_json('post_not found', 400, 'msg') unless post
    return post
  end
  def render_json(data, status_code, main_key = 'data')
    render json: { "#{main_key}": data }, status: status_code and return 
  end
end

class PostController < FrequentMethodController
  def view_post
     post_id = params[:post_id]
     post = post_exist?(post_id)
     # test code 
     render_json(post, 1, 'data')
 end
end
```

and try using `render direct`  but not work

```
   render :json => { :msg => 'post not found ' },:status => 400 and return
```

Use `'rails', '5.1.4'`

Answer (score 1):

```rb
class FrequentMethodController < ApplicationController
  def post_exist?(post_id)
    post = Post.find_by_id(post_id)
    render_json('post_not found', 400, 'msg') unless post
    return post # <------------------------------------------------------------ THIS
  end

  def render_json(data, status_code, main_key = 'data')
    render json: { "#{main_key}": data }, status: status_code and return # <--- AND THIS
  end
end
```

Rails sees a `return` first in the `render_json` method and, when it exits that method it sees another return in `post_exists?`

Try moving your return outside of the `render_json` method:

```rb
class FrequentMethodController < ApplicationController
  def post_exist?(post_id)
    post = Post.find_by_id(post_id)
    render_json('post_not found', 400, 'msg') and return unless post
    return post
  end

  def render_json(data, status_code, main_key = 'data')
    render json: { "#{main_key}": data }, status: status_code
  end
end
```

You could also eliminate the `and return` with an `if` statement:

```rb
class FrequentMethodController < ApplicationController
  def post_exist?(post_id)
    post = Post.find_by_id(post_id)

    if post
      return post
    else
      render_json('post_not found', 400, 'msg')
      # if this is the only place render_json is used, I wouldn't bother making it a method
      # render json: { 'msg': 'post_not found' }, status: 400
    end
  end

  def render_json(data, status_code, main_key = 'data')
    render json: { "#{main_key}": data }, status: status_code
  end
end
```

### UPDATE:

There's actually a TRIPLE return going on here when we start with PostController.

1. Rails visits `PostController#view_post`
2. Rails goes to `FrequentMethodController#post_exists?`
3. While still inside `FrequentMethodController#post_exists?`, Rails goes to `FrequentMethodController#render_json?` and finds **return #1**
4. Rails goes back up to `FrequentMethodController#post_exists?`and finds **return #2**
5. Rails goes back to `PostController#view_post` and sees `render_json` (AGAIN!!)
6. Rails goes to `FrequentMethodController#post_exists?` and finds **return #3**

This code is spaghetti.

If `FrequentMethodController` is really just a helper file, then I think it should *never* have a `return`. Keep early `return`s to a minimum, and only in the main controller for the model.

Early returns *are* helpful to clean up complicated and nested if statements and potentially make code more readable, but you don't have that problem here. In fact, all these returns have made your code brittle, unpredictable, and overly complicated.

Overall, I think `FrequentMethodController` is a BAD idea.

- I think `post_exist?(post_id)` should return either true or false.
- I think `render_json` is simple enough that it shouldn't be it's own method.

AND, you've [hijacked the normal CRUD structure](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

I would do something this instead:

```rb
class PostController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # changed name from view_post
  def show
     if @post
       render @post.as_json
     else
       render json: { 'msg': 'post_not found' }, status: 400
     end
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**Note that the above code has NO explicit returns** and requires no manual helper files.

Comment: not fix problem when call with another controller `PostController < FrequentMethodController`

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why did you even create `FrequentMethodController`? Just use `ApplicationHelper` for reusable methods across Controllers. PostController should inherit from ApplicationController directly.

Comment: i add FrequentMethod in FrequentMethodController and inherit to other controllers

Comment: @TalaatMagdy, see my update. I think you've gone off the rails. I think you'll have a much easier time by sticking to more standard conventions for routes and controllers.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
def view_post
  post_id = params[:post_id]
  if post = post_exist?(post_id)
    # test code 
    render_json(post, 1, 'data')
  end
end
```